# Please explain OpenSSL CVE-2022-3786 'sizeof' change

Tags: c, openssl, sizeof, cve

What is difference between these 2 sizeof operator uses?

From here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/680e65b94c916af259bfdc2e25f1ab6e0c7a97d6?diff=split

```
unsigned int *pDecoded
```

...

```
memmove(pDecoded + i + 1, pDecoded + i, (written_out - i) * sizeof *pDecoded);
memmove(pDecoded + i + 1, pDecoded + i, (written_out - i) * sizeof (*pDecoded));
```

I think `sizeof *PDecoded` returns sizeof pointer to unsigned int.
Whereas, `sizeof (*pDecoded)` returns sizeof unsigned int.

Comment: It's style preference, in this case there is no functional difference.

Comment: The official OpenSSL coding style document requires that parens be used for sizeof - although they are not required by the language: https://www.openssl.org/policies/technical/coding-style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference; these expressions are equivalent.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int *foo;

    printf("sizeof foo <%zu> | sizeof *foo <%zu> or <%zu>\n",
            sizeof foo, sizeof *foo, sizeof (*foo));
}
```

Output (on my machine):

```
sizeof foo <8> | sizeof *foo <4> or <4>
```

This looks like a style choice. The only other use of [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) in the file also has superfluous parenthesis:

```
char a_ulabel[LABEL_BUF_SIZE + 1];
size_t a_size = sizeof(a_ulabel);
```

The parenthesis are only required when the [operand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is a *type*:

```
sizeof (int)
```

Otherwise, they are used to influence [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).